# Read zipped binary file in C++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I used to use `popen(("zcat " + filename).c_str(), "r")` to read zipped text files. However, I need read zipped binary file this time. I tried `popen(("zcat " + filename).c_str(), "rb")` but it failed as the return value is NULL even if the file does exist.

May I know why the way fails? I can guarantee the filename is properly defined, no special characters and the file does exist. The similar way works when I read zipped text files.

May I know what should be the correct way to do that?

Comment: Why don't you use a proper Zip library rather than depending on pipes? Smashing the filename on the end of the command-line is wrong, it won't work with filenames that have spaces or irregular characters in them, so if you can avoid doing that, do avoid it.

Comment: Hi @tadman, the problem is that we want to avoid installing more libraries. If we can do it without library that will be great.

Comment: What operating system are you targeting? Many have some kind of library already installed, and that's a non-issue if you can build an executable with the library statically linked inside. It's better to depend on a library than some arbitrary shell command being available. This code allows people to execute arbitrary shell commands if they control the filename, so that's super bad.

Comment: @tadman, we are targeting Ubuntu. What libraries are you recommending?

Comment: What's wrong with [`zlib`](http://www.zlib.net/)?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I was going to say the same thing. It's super standard and I'm not even sure you can find a distro without that even on the most stripped down install.

Comment: Another reason not using libraries is because the old codes does not. I prefer using a similar way when I extend the functionalities. Should I do that?

Comment: I will try zlib first. I am not familiar though. Any idea why my way fails? I can confirm the filename is correct.

Comment: @JerryChou "Another reason not using libraries is because the old codes does not." A bad code is bad no matter how old or 'traditional' it is. Better isolate the way you read a zip in a function/method/interface and revisit/refactor your old code to call into it. At later time, if you want to change the 'archive reading provider' you only need to make the change in exactly one place.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"rb"` isn't a valid mode for `popen`. If you read [the man page for `popen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), you'll see it says:

> ```
> FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The `type` argument is a pointer to a null-terminated string which must contain either the letter `'r'` for reading or the letter `'w'` for writing.
>
> [...]

If you look at [the POSIX documentation for `fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html), it says (regarding the mode string):

> The character `'b'` shall have no effect, but is allowed for ISO C standard conformance.

Thus, on a POSIX-ish system (like Linux), you don't need to specify binary mode when opening files, especially when using `popen`. Any `FILE*` you get back from `popen` will always be opened in binary mode.

---

If you decide to use zlib instead of `popen("zcat", ...)` (as other suggest, and I might recommend) there's a lot of good documentation, and I have personally found the [`zpipe.c`](http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c) demo very helpful.

Comment: So is it still possible to use popen for what I need?

Comment: Yes. I just updated my answer to talk about this point. In Linux (and other POSIX systems), `FILE*` handles from `popen` are *always* in binary mode, so you don't need to worry about specifying that with your call to `popen`.